# Is there a way to tell ReSharper to retain some old styles?

Tags: resharper

While I like a lot of the improvements Microsoft has made in ASP.NET, I don't like eliminating `main(string[]args)` and eliminating `{...}` for namespaces.

Is there a way to tell ReSharper I want it to suggest the old way for both of these cases?

Comment: It would be good to add more detail to your question including what version of VS and ReSharper you are using and what .NET framework you are targeting. For what it's worth, block-scoped (old style) namespaces are a waste of indentation (I have never seen a file contain more than one namespace block (and if it did it should be two files anyway). Top-level statements is more of a Marmite (love/hate) preference though :)

Comment: @PiersMyers I had the why in the original question and it got edited out. I guess that was straying into the world of opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For namespaces, `ReSharper`->`Options...`->`Code Editing`->`C#`->`Syntax Style`->`Code body`->`Namespaces` select `Block-scoped` option.

[image]

Top-level statements (without `main`) are now an option when you create new projects in Visual Studio.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. And I assume there's no setting for prefering a main() body.

Comment: When creating a new project, Visual Studio now gives you the option to not use top-level statements and with use `main` instead. I have updated my answer.